SQL/PLSQL - Take after some special characters
I am trying to get the value from the itnum field which is TEST1234. (Need inside the two single quote)
filter=‘(itnum = ‘’TEST1234’’) AND (dbnum like ‘’Y%’’)’

Tried something like this but unable to get
select nvl(substr(@filter, 15, instr(@filter, ‘=‘) -1), @filter) AS output from dual

Can someone help me to achieve?

These fancy quotes won't work, Oracle won't recognize them. If you write query in e.g. MS Word, don't do that; use an ordinary text editor.
As of the question itself: what is "@filter"? It doesn't belong to PL/SQL nor Oracle's pure SQL.
You said you want to get value from itnum field (column, I presume?). Which value? What does "need inside two single quotes" actually mean? Why do you need two single quotes? Could you post test case which shows what you have, explain rules which have to be applied to it and desired result?

This is the MOCA programming language, mostly it will be in SQL statement. itnum value needs to be derived from the Filter column which is inside the two single quotes.  filter column has the value ‘(itnum = ‘’TEST1234’’) AND (dbnum like ‘’Y%’’)’ and the expected output from the filter column is TEST1234

Column filter has the value ‘(itnum = ‘’AB123-352’’) AND (dbnum like ‘’Y%’’)’ and the expected output from the filter column is AB124-352

In Oracle, you can use:
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(
         filter,
         q'[\(itnum\s*=\s*'([^']*)'\)]',
         1,
         1,
         NULL,
         1
       ) AS itnum
FROM   table_name;

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (filter) AS
SELECT q'[(itnum = 'TEST1234') AND (dbnum like 'Y%')]' FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



ITNUM




TEST1234




If you are passing filter as a bind variable then:
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(
         :filter,
         q'[\(itnum\s*=\s*'([^']*)'\)]',
         1,
         1,
         NULL,
         1
       ) AS itnum
FROM   DUAL;

fiddle
